# How did Sudama die?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana, death

The story of Sri Krishna and Sudama (Kuchela) is well known by everyone. But not much detail is known about Sudama after Sri Krishna alleviated his poverty. So, what happened after he was blessed richness.

How did he die? Is there any account for this?

Comment: The story of Krishna-Sudama is not found in the Mahabharata (MB). So most likely a later invention in Bhagavata (SB). Anything found in Bhagavata or Harivamsa but not present in MB, just take the message and leave the story. If you start digging deep you'll be left with more questions than answers.

Comment: Which is good. More questions, more answers and hence more knowledge. I have already taken theb message.

Comment: The closest story you'll come across in MB is the Drupada-Drona one where Drona finds himself in abject poverty and remembers his old friend Drupada. But Drona is insulted & his request is turned down. So the SB authors created the Krishna-Sudama story with a different ending and a better message.

Comment: "More questions => more answers" – not necessarily, see [this meta post](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/760/2995).

Comment: @sv. The Puranas are just as old as the Mahabharata.  And the Mahabharata is not devoted to the life of Krishna, so the fact that a particular incident is not mentioned there means nothing.  The Mahabharata mostly only discusses incidents involving Krishna insofar as they relate in some way to the story of the Pandavas and Kauravas.

Answer (score 4):

After Sudama(Kuchela) was blessed with richness by Krishna, Sudama performed charity to brahmanas and meditated on Krishna. Sudama, along with his wife, reached Lord Krishna's supreme abode after his human life.

> Engaged in meditating on Lord Krishna's lotus feet and giving charity
>   to the brahmanas, **Sudama and his wife finally returned to Lord
>   Krishna's supreme abode**.
>
> [[Text 80, Chapter 22: The Story of Shri Sudama-vipra, Canto 6, Garga Samhita]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_6.22:_The_Story_of_Shri_Sudama-vipra)